# How can I navigate inside an application with just my keyboard? (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am a keyboard man. I dislike having to take my hand away from the keyboard to use the mouse, it really slows down my working pace.

I can easily navigate through folder icons, folders, web pages and more, but there is 1 little problem with applications.

I can usually use tab to browse through fields such as a form in an application.
However, if in that same window there are 2 forms, tab will not move to the other form, and I can only switch windows which leaves a big gap in what I can do with a keyboard.

Is there a way to get to that other form in the same window with just the keyboard?
(If not, definitely think there should be a native way of doing this rather than relying on developers.)

Comment: Can you define "Form" a little more for us (screenshot maybe)? Just so we know exactly what's in question. :)

Comment: The form I am referring to is from a company application, so I can not provide a screenshot of that.

Think of a HTML Form for inputting data, or a system application for inputting data.
Then think of more than 1 of the above in a single window.

Pressing tab works only within 1 form, switching between forms is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that the application was not written with proper keyboard support. There is very little you can do about this other than ask nicely for a change.

One extreme option would be to enable the keyboard controlled mouse (it's an accessibility feature) which allows you to use the direction arrows to move the cursor around.

Comment: Yeh, seems that way :/
Unfortunately, developers don't often think about keyboarders.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have a few suggestions to encourage keeping your fingers on the keys. They may resolve the issue you are facing when you would like to navigate between two different application windows and their corresponding input fields.

---

## Never Touch the Mouse:

<kbd>F6</kbd> allows you to cycle through screen elements & <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> allows you to switch between open applications. You can cycle through screen elements in much the same way you switch between open applications. In the Google Chrome browser, for instance, pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> cycles through the following screen elements:

1. The omnibox is selected for input and if a URL is present its text is selected.
2. If your bookmarks bar is open, then your first bookmark is selected. Pressing enter would of course navigate your browser to that web page. You can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through your bookmarks here as well.
3. The web page you are currently browsing is selected. You can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through various elements on the page (Hyperlinks, input fields, etc.).

It is worth noting that the cycling of the <kbd>F6</kbd> shortcut depends on the context of the application. For instance, if your bookmarks bar isn't open in Google Chrome, then there will be no bookmarks bar to cycle through.

## Touch the Mouse First:

You can quickly input data into specific fields in multiple application windows by selecting the input field of each application first. When you get to the last application that you need to select a field input for press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch back to your first application and begin inputting data without touching your mouse! Of course, all good things come to an end and you'll have to use your mouse again when you finish the inputting the field on the last application you selected...

Or do you?

You can find more Windows keyboard shortcuts on the [Keyboard-Shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8) page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
It doesn't solve my problem, but did point out some helpful information, especially about F6.
Works great on the desktop and in Chrome, will be of help.
(Can't vote up because I need 15 reputation apparently : /)